# How to disable DocView mode (completely)?

Tags: docview

I found [here](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/disabling-doc-view-mode-td61909.html) that the following disables DocView mode for a specific file type, like PDF:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pdf\\'" . fundamental-mode))
```

But how can DocView mode be disabled completely, for any file type? (on GNU Emacs 26.1)

Comment: Did you try: `(rassq-delete-all #'doc-view-mode auto-mode-alist)`? The thread you link to suggests this is what you want.

Comment: Just tried, thanks, Tyler (I must have missed that). But it didn't work. JPGs still show up in DocView (even PDFs now that I removed the above).

Comment: See @Stefan comment, I think it needs to be: `(rassq-delete-all #'doc-view-mode-maybe auto-mode-alist)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the `(rassq-delete-all #'doc-view-mode-maybe auto-mode-alist)` suggested by Tyler (but note you need to use `...-maybe`), you can also be more drastic:

```
;; Die, Doc-View-mode! die!
(defalias 'doc-view-mode #'doc-view-fallback-mode) ;Or fundamental-mode, ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, the `#'fundamental-mode` seems to work, but not for `.jpg` files. Is that normal? (minibuffer shows `(Image[jpeg])` but file is still displayed as an image). Could that be something other than DocView? So I'm in dired-mode, hit RET on a .jpg file and that shows me the picture in the current buffer. Hmmm, even if I use `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Ahhh, it's image mode! You can toggle via 'C-c C-c', *then* you see the source, great, thanks!

Comment: I think "DocView" and "Image" don't start with the same letter, so there's a good chance it's not the same thing ;-)

Comment: ok, so now I need a `die, DocView *and* Image mode, die!` :-) Sometimes Emacs is just too smart...

Comment: ... and since `C-c C-c` also works in doc-view mode, one should probably just remember that and not disable it at all (for consistency).